# HTML Canvas Element wont show up

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Inversion</title>
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="loadlevel()" id="levelsel">
    <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
    <div
        id="message"
    > Hi </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code. When I delete

```
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

the button and the message "Hi" shows up. When that section is included, nothing shows up. Eventually I want it to show a series of 32x32 pixel images to make a map for a simple game. I am using Chrome and it is up to date. I also have a CSS file that should be making the height and width of the canvas 832px and 672px respectively.

Comment: You need to set the width and height of the canvas element with attributes as well. Please post the relevant drawing logic as well.

Comment: @Phix this is not true. The default size of `<canvas>` is 300x150 and that's defined as a standard.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank You.